# Determining if set of polynomials is a Grobner basis

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is exercise 7 from *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little, and Shea.

If we use grlex order with $x > y> z$, is $\{x^4 y^2 - z^5, x^3 y^3 - 1, x^2 y^4 - 2z\}$ a grobner basis for the ideal generated by these polynomials?

Definition: Given a non-zero ideal $I \subseteq k[x_1, \cdots, k_n]$ and a monomial ordering on $k[x_1,  \cdots, x_n]$, a set $G = \{g_1, \cdots, g_t\} \subseteq I$ is called a Grobner basis (or standard basis) for $I$ if $\langle LT(g_1), \cdots, LT(g_t)\rangle = \langle LT(I) \rangle$.

I am specifically confused on how to write $\langle LT(I) \rangle$.

By glex order, I write $\langle LT(g_1), \cdots, LT(g_t)\rangle = \langle LT(I) \rangle = \langle x^4 y^2, x^3 y^3, x^2y^4\rangle$. I must check that this is a subset of $\langle LT(I) \rangle$ and vice-versa.

But how do I write $\langle LT(I) \rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for clarity, the exercise is in section 2.5 of the book.

The inclusion $\langle LT(g_1),\ldots,LT(g_t)\rangle \subset \langle LT(I) \rangle$ always holds, as $\{g_1,\ldots,g_t\} \subset I$ and $\langle LT(I) \rangle$ is the ideal generated by elements of $LT(I) = \{LT(f) \mid f \in I, f \neq 0\}$. You have correctly identified the leading terms in the left-hand side. The question is whether there exists nonzero $f \in I$ such that $LT(f) \not\in \langle LT(g_1),\ldots,LT(g_t) \rangle$.

That is, can you make a linear combination (with polynomial coefficients) of $g_1,\ldots,g_t$ such that the result has its leading term not in $\langle LT(g_1),\ldots,LT(g_t) \rangle$? A natural idea is to make a linear combination such that the "would-be" leading term (looking at the leading terms of the summands) would cancel, so that you get a "possibly new" leading term. In this particular case we have e.g. $LT(g_1) = x^4y^2$ and $LT(g_2) = x^3y^3$, so we can multiply $g_1$ by $y$ and $g_2$ by $x$ to get the same leading terms $LT(yg_1) = x^4y^3$ and $LT(xg_2) = x^4y^3$, and now we consider the linear combination $f=yg_1 - xg_2 \in I$. In fact $f=yg_1 - xg_2 = y(x^4y^2 - z^5) - x(x^3y^3-1) = -yz^5 + x$, so its leading term is $LT(f) = -yz^5$, and this is not contained in the ideal $\langle x^4y^2, x^3y^3,x^2y^4 \rangle$. Recall that checking membership of a monomial in a monomial ideal is easy; see Lemma 2 of section 2.4 in the book. So we have found a nonzero $f \in I$ such that $LT(f) \not\in \langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),LT(g_3) \rangle$, and hence $\{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ is not a Groebner basis.

This heuristic idea leads to the definition of the S-polynomial later in the book (the next paragraph 2.6), and from there to Buchberger's criterion and Buchberger's algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. Your explanation was very good. Question: how do we know if we simply cannot find a counter example or if there are none?

Comment: You're welcome. A systematic method to check whether a generating set is a Gröbner basis is Buchberger's criterion, which is explained in the next section §2.6. Sometimes you can come up with alternative arguments, as seen also in this section §2.5, shortly after the definition of a Gröbner basis.